# checkout steps are not expanding niether working magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I had updated a custom theme in magento 1.9 all goes well but Iam unable to expand checkout steps.

It says: `<div id="checkout-step-login" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">`

when I Change it as `<div id="checkout-step-login" class="step a-item" style="display:block;">`

Step is visible but now Iam not able to continue further to second step.

If I change the theme to (rwd theme) then checkout steps expand well and also run well

what I am missing in my custom theme that unables the checkout steps to expand and work correctly? PLEASE HELP

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: yes. TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function ---prototype.js (line 5653, col 8)
TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function  ---opcheckout.js (line 295)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this into you theme register.phtml file and try again.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" /> <!-- added -->
```

Comment: can you give me the path of register.phtml and where to add this :  getFormKey()?

Comment: app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml.   add this: <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" /> <!-- added -->

Comment: Hello it still does not work. I had added : <?php echo $this->getFormKey(); ?> after <form>. It still giving error in console: TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
prototype.js (line 5653, col 8)
TypeError: $(...).setAttribute is not a function
/canadi...nepage/ (line 1081, col 32)
TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function
opcheckout.js (line 295)
TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function
opcheckout.js (line 596)
3
TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
prototype.js (line 5653, col 8)

Answer (score -1):

It might be the jquery library issue. Open element inspector and check the errors in the console window. If there is any jquery library related issue, fix them.
In my case, i had missed the opcheckout.js library. Adding opcheckout.js script fixed the issue for me.